# Usage of the Past Perfect of "to be" for 2 (discrete) past events?

Tags: grammar, past-tense

> 1. He **wasn't** resolute thus he confabulated with her.

How would I rewrite this sentence using the past perfect tense, because I sense that the sentence above currently is flawed?

The first action was his lack of resoluteness, so **wasn't** should be in the past perfect. Yet this sounds wrong. Is it?

> `2.` He **hadn't been**  resolute thus he confabulated with her.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of them are wrong, but they have slightly different meanings.  The first one is saying that the reason he confabulated with her was because he was not a resolute person at the time of the conversation.  The second is saying that the reason is that at some point prior to the conversation he had acted in an irresolute manner.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the bit you're asking about, but if it was my sentence I wouldn't use "confabulated", which is a word normally used in a non-serious, slightly facetious sense. If you weren't intending that, I'd replace it with "consulted her". Also, put a comma after "resolute".